# How to add list of value in dataframe column

Tags: r

I'm beginning for r programming language, help me how to add list of value in data frame columns.

my expected  data frame will be.

```
U_ID       Value       

 1        list(`First`="ty",'Second'="89")                                                     
 2        list(`First`= c("20","10","40"),`Second`="user")                                      
 3        list(`First`="vendor",`Second`="yu",`Four`=list(list(`ty`="78",'pt'="kkkpp")))         
 4        NULL                                                                                   
 5        list(`First`="client")
```

Comment: Use `data.frame(U_ID = 1:5, value = I(list(...)))`

Comment: @akrun,Thanks for response ,working fine ,But my doubt is i'm using list object for each column ,but it returns class(df$value)  is  "AsIs".why it will not return "list".Is their any possibilities to return  class(df$value)  is  "list".

Comment: In that case you consider using `dplyr::data_frame` It returns a `tibble` i.e. `data_frame(U_ID = 1:5, value =list(1:5, 1:3, NULL, 4, 6:10))`  THe `AsIs` attribute is fine except having some issues when u try to `relist` or so.  Then, you have to remove the attributes before doing that.  It is just an attribute `- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"`
.  You can check `is.list(res$value)#
[1] TRUE` if the object name is `res`

Comment: Another option is to create the U_ID column first and then create the second column by assigning i.e. `res <- data.frame(U_ID = 1:5);res$value <- list(1:5, 1:3, NULL, 4, 6:10)`

Comment: @akrun,I got it ,thanks for your explanation.